# How do I solve this error of nested routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application implemented in rails, what happens is that I want to access the following url: `http://localhost:3000/academics/students/1/schedules`, but when trying to access the following error appears: `Routing Error uninitialized constant Academics::SchedulesController`

The problem is that I could not do it for nested resources, since schedules already exist for students in another route, and the previous route of academics is for administrators, with other independent routes. The schedule controller in academics was created in the following way: `class Academics::Students::SchedulesController < ApplicationController`

Is there any way for this to work with the previous implementation?

The `route.rb` resource academics:

```
  namespace :academics do
    resources :subjects
    namespace :students do
      resources :schedules
    end
    resources :groups
  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do:

```
namespace :academics do
  resources :subjects
  resources :students do
    scope module: :students do 
      resources :schedules
    end
  end
  resources :groups
end
```

Then you'll get (amongst other things):

```
    academics_student_schedules GET    /academics/students/:student_id/schedules(.:format)          academics/students/schedules#index
                                POST   /academics/students/:student_id/schedules(.:format)          academics/students/schedules#create
 new_academics_student_schedule GET    /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/new(.:format)      academics/students/schedules#new
edit_academics_student_schedule GET    /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/:id/edit(.:format) academics/students/schedules#edit
     academics_student_schedule GET    /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/:id(.:format)      academics/students/schedules#show
                                PATCH  /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/:id(.:format)      academics/students/schedules#update
                                PUT    /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/:id(.:format)      academics/students/schedules#update
                                DELETE /academics/students/:student_id/schedules/:id(.:format)      academics/students/schedules#destroy
```

This will route:

```
/academics/students/1/schedules
```

To the `index` action of the `Academics::Students::SchedulesController`.

BTW, I'm not sure if you literally have spaces in your class definition (i.e., `class Academics :: Students :: SchedulesController < ApplicationController`) as shown in your question. If so, that seems unusual to me. But, if it works, that would be interesting.